# Self-diagnostic test for software layers?

Tags: testing, diagnostics, automated-tests

With the increasing effort put into dividing software pieces into independent layers and decoupling them using dynamic discovery and dependency injection, it has become harder to determine which "layer" in the system is contributing to a system-wide failure of the "application".

Unit tests help by making sure that all "modules" that makes up a layer is working as expected. But unit tests are written in a such a way that each "modules" are isolated by using techniques such as stubbing and mocking.

Consider the simplistic example below:

L1. Database -> L2. Database Layer -> L3. Windows Service -> L4. Client Application

For instance, if the database engine is down, then the system will not operate normally. It will be hard to tell if the database engine is really down or that there is a bug in the database layer (L2) code. To check, you would have to launch some kind of a database management tool to check if the database engine is running.

What we are trying to achieve is a developer tool that can be launched whenever "there is something wrong" with the system, and this tool will "query" each layer for their "integrity" or "diagnostic" data. The tool will provide the list of software layers and their "integrity status". It will then be able to say, right off the bat, that layer X is the cause of the issue (I.e. The database engine is down).

Of course, each layer will be responsible for providing its own "diagnostic method" that can be queried by the tool.

I guess what we're trying to achieve here is some kind of an "Integration Test" framework or something similar that can be used in run-time (not compile/build time like a unit test). The inspiration came from physical devices that have their own "On-board Diagnostics" like cars. A good example in the software world is the Power-on Self Test that is being run every time the computer is being turned-on.

Have anyone seen or heard something like this? Any suggestions or pointers will surely help a lot!

Answer (score 0):

You could have a common interface that each layer would implement as a WCF service. This way you could connect to every layer and diagnose it. Having this diagnostics available might be useful but if you want to implement it everywhere (every layer) it will be another thing that may fail - how would you diagnose that? Your system would swarm with WCF services which is not good as it requires a lot of maintenance and makes it less stable. Plus it requires a lot of work to implement.

Alternative that I would suggest is to have a good logging system in place. Minimum would be to have every module log an error in all `catch` sections but I suggest more than that especially for debug purposes. I recommend using Log4Net which is free and very flexible. It is effective in not logging when it is not required meaning that you can set the logging level high and it does not impact performance even in production code. You can change logging level during runtime by changing a setting in a config file. I use Log4Net a lot and it works well.

Once you have your code logging stuff you can configure Log4Net so that all logs go into a central database. You would then have one place where you could relatively easy diagnose what's going on, what has failed, where and what was the exception or message. You can even set up email messages to be sent when something goes wrong.